# Find files and replace the part of the name of them in Bash

Tags: macos, bash, replace, find, filenames

I know how to look for files that includes characters and put the extension after the names of the files.
For example,
`find . -name "name1*" -exec mv {} {}.bak`

After executing this code,
`name111 name11 kname1 name2 name3`
will be
`name111.bak name11.bak kname1 name2 name3`.

However, I would like to know how to replace the part of the file name.
For example, I would like to replace
`name111 name11 kname1 name2 name3`
with
`name222 name22 kname2 name2 name3`

In this case, I looked for files that include `1` and replaced `1` with `2`.

My environment is OS X 10.10 Public Beta 5.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I edited this question because I found I made a mistake, and a answer has disappeared. I'm sorry for the person who answered this question. I'll never edit this question from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
find . -name "name1*" -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(echo "{}" | tr 1 2)"' \;
```

please test it in some files that you have backed up!

That finds the files you want and then executes `sh` on each of them. Inside the shell script, it uses `mv` to rename the file from its original name to its name with all the `1`s transliterated into `2`s.

The above will maybe not do what you want if you have a file called `name1` in a directory called `/something1or2/with/another/1/in/it` because it will replace the `1`s in the directory path too - but maybe you don't have that!

Comment: Thanks. It worked. In addition, I could replace two or more characters.
`find . -name "name1*" -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(echo "{}" | sed 's/name1/name2/g')"' \;`

Comment: Then, I would like to know how to replace only the last extension. For example, I want to replace `name1.flv name2.flv name3.flv flv.flv` with `name1.mp4 name2.mp4 name3.mp4 flv.mp4`. If you execute `find . -name "name*" -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(echo "{}" | sed 's/flv/mp4/g')"' \;`, `name1.flv name2.flv name3.flv flv.flv` will be `name1.mp4 name2.mp4 name3.mp4 mp4.mp4`.

Comment: And is there any way to prevent from replacing the `1`s in the directory path? I will use this code in my application source, so I can't decide that the user of my app doesn't have that.

Comment: I could replace only the last extension with this command: `find . -name "*flv*" -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(echo "{}" | sed s/\.[^.]*$/.mp4/g )"' \;`
Now, All I want to do is prevent from replacing the 1s in the directory path.

Comment: And I found that `sh -c 'something'` isn't needed. In other words, `find . -name "*flv*" -exec mv "{}" "$(echo "{}" | sed s/\.[^.]*$/.mp4/g )" \;` also worked.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Without `sh -c`, the command wasn't executed correctly.